# Trouble with XCode8 StoryBoard display

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

Recently i've upgraded to XCode8  and i've projects created with XCode7 , after that i've opened my storyboard and it looks a little bit weird it shows only blue squares. is this normal all there's any configuration to do . There's how it looks like [StoryBoard in my XCode8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2QxU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.  Despite xcode "supporting" the latest version of El Capitan, it doesn't really.  I upgraded to Sierra, and as soon as I did, the Storyboard started to render the screens as expected.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was the probleme of the OS version i've upgraded to sierra and downloaded the XCode 8 everything is Okey thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem. This is called "`Bounds`" rectangles lines. You can hide them from `XCode: Editor > canvas > show Bounds rectangles.`

Comment: Thank you for you answer but that didn't work , because if tried to put imageview into a prototype cell of a tableview and assign an image  to it but the same thing happen only a blue rectangle appear (i have many prototype cells in my tableview) , this how it look [storyboard display][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DiA4.png